# WSO2 ESB Get Username

Tags: security, wso2, esb

I like to use a proxy with authentification via username and password. All the messages going over the ESB should be saved into a Database, including the user which is authenticated to the ESB.
Is there a way to get the username in the proxy? I know you can get the message-id for example, but I couldn't find a solution to get the username.

Maybe you can help me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once proxy service is secured user name token or basic auth...  After successful message authentication,  user name can be retrieved. User name can be retrieved from axis2 message context using property called  "username".  You can use property mediator (scope is axis2) or simple class mediator.

Comment: This goes into the right direction, but I still have problems getting this property. I don't know how the expression should look like: 
<property name="benutzer" expression="get-property('username')" scope="axis2" type="STRING"/>
Can you help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

It's working if you use $header to access the header information. Just get the xPath and extract the username like this example:

```
<property xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" name="user" expression="$header/wsse:Security/wsse:UsernameToken/wsse:Username"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can secure proxies using username token(ie: username/password). Go to service dashboard-->security option and you can find the tools to enable username token.
If you secured like that, in your request you should send the basic auth header.

Comment: Sorry, answer doesn't fit the question.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can get help from the ESB documentation here
http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/ESB460/HTTP+Basic+Authentication+over+a+Proxy+Server

Comment: Sorry, answer doesn't fit the question.